# vue test utils get offsetWidth is 0

Tags: vue-test-utils

I tried to get the value of `offsetwidth` but it was always `0`

**Template.spec.js**

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Template from '~/components/Template.vue';
describe('Template', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(Template);
  it('get offsetWidth', async () => {
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick()
    console.log(wrapper.element.offsetWidth)  // 0
  });
});
```

**Template.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="template" style="width:100px">
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: I have the same problem in the mounted, you got any fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your CSS.  if the class of .template contains any of the following rules, the result you are receiving is expected. Elements that will not be displayed, may not be included in the flow.

**your-stylesheet.css**

```
display: none;
overflow: hidden;
float: left;
height: 0;   /* will be 0 without any content in the element */
position: absolute;
```

** There may be others, but any of those may cause the issue.  Just make sure that there is content and that it is displayed prior to trying to measure it.

Good Luck!

Comment: External style sheets don't typically get loaded by tests. I generated a basic vue app, it didn't have an external stylesheet and for good measure I also removed the "template" class from the html. The result was the same as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the CSS styles as well as `offsetWidth` in your test files but it can only be done after the tag is rendered.

```js
element.style.width = '100px'
Object.defineProperties(element, {
  offsetWidth: { value: 100 },
  clientWidth: { value: 100 },
})
```